# Converting an array of weeks/day to an organized object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have an array of objects that have a format like this:

```
const program = [
  { id: '1', week: 1, day: 1, description: 'week 1 day 1', completed: true },
  { id: '2', week: 1, day: 2, description: 'week 1 day 2', completed: true },
  { id: '3', week: 1, day: 3, description: 'week 1, day 3', completed: true },
  { id: '4', week: 2, day: 1, description: 'week 2, day 1', completed: true },
  { id: '5', week: 2, day: 2, description: 'week 2 day 2', completed: false },
  { id: '6', week: 2, day: 3, description: 'week 2 day 3', completed: true },
  { id: '7', week: 3, day: 1, description: 'week 3, day 1', completed: false },
  // ....
  { id: '89', week: 11, day: 9, description: 'week 11, day 9', completed: false },
  // ...
];
```

and I want the output to look something like this:

```
const weekMap = {
  1: [
    { id: '1', week: 1, day: 1, description: 'week 1 day 1', completed: true },
    { id: '2', week: 1, day: 2, description: 'week 1 day 2', completed: true },
    { id: '3', week: 1, day: 3, description: 'week 1, day 3', completed: true },
  ],
  2: [
    { id: '4', week: 2, day: 1, description: 'week 2, day 1', completed: true },
    { id: '5', week: 2, day: 2, description: 'week 2 day 2', completed: false },
    { id: '6', week: 2, day: 3, description: 'week 2 day 3', completed: true },
  ],
  3: [
    { id: '7', week: 3, day: 1, description: 'week 3, day 1', completed: false },
    // ....
  ],
  11: [
    { id: '89', week: 11, day: 9, description: 'week 11, day 9', completed: false },
    // ....
  ],
};
```

So far what I've tried was `.reduce`

```
export const toWeekMap = (programSteps) =>
  programSteps.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    if (!acc[curr.week]) {
      acc[curr.week] = [];
    }

    if (!acc[curr.week][curr.day]) {
      acc[curr.week][curr.day] = [];
    }

    console.log(acc);

    return acc[curr.week][curr.day].push(curr);
  }, {});
```

Though this doesn't work and I'm not sure of any ways around it. The error I get is

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot create property '1' on number '1'`

Obviously there's something very off with my logic... maybe I'm misunderstanding `.reduce`?

Comment: instead of acc[curr.week][curr.day].push(curr) why don't you just acc[curr.week].push(curr) ? your weekMap[1] is an array of objects. You could type weekMap as : { [idWeek: number]: any }[] (do not use any, it's just for the example)

Comment: `return acc[curr.week][curr.day].push(curr);` this doesn't return "acc" like expected, it returns the result of "push" which is a number.

Comment: What you need is group by week number. This is common operation on collections. Lodash has such utility, see groupBy. It will allow you to achive result without mutations, unlike all published answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main mistake of your code is in this line:

```
return acc[curr.week][curr.day].push(curr);
```

This is the equivalent of saying:

```
const a = acc[curr.week][curr.day].push(curr);
return a;
```

`a` will contain the return value of the push function, which is the new length of the array.

What you actually want to do is:

```
acc[curr.week][curr.day].push(curr);
return acc;
```

After that, you can fix your logic inside the reduce according to your needs. If I understood correctly what you want, this should do:

```js
const program = [
  { id: '1', week: 1, day: 1, description: 'week 1 day 1', completed: true },
  { id: '2', week: 1, day: 2, description: 'week 1 day 2', completed: true },
  { id: '3', week: 1, day: 3, description: 'week 1, day 3', completed: true },
  { id: '4', week: 2, day: 1, description: 'week 2, day 1', completed: true },
  { id: '5', week: 2, day: 2, description: 'week 2 day 2', completed: false },
  { id: '6', week: 2, day: 3, description: 'week 2 day 3', completed: true },
  { id: '7', week: 3, day: 1, description: 'week 3, day 1', completed: false },
  // ....
  { id: '89', week: 11, day: 9, description: 'week 11, day 9', completed: false },
  // ...
];


const toWeekMap = (programSteps) =>
  programSteps.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  
    if (!acc[curr.week]) {
      acc[curr.week] = [];
    }


     acc[curr.week].push(curr);
     return acc;
  }, {});
  console.log(toWeekMap(program))
```

Answer (score 3):

Hello you can try this :

```
 export const toWeekMap = (programSteps) =>
        programSteps.reduce((acc, curr) => {
           (acc[curr.week] = acc[curr.week] || []).push(curr);
            return acc;
    }, {});
```

Comment: Up vote as this solution shows how to initialize the array property and push to it in a single line.  And that trick is very useful sometimes. +1

Answer (score 1):

The usage of the `reduce` is good. However, the logic of building the desired object is flawed at one point. Here is the correction

```
export const toWeekMap = (programSteps) =>
  programSteps.reduce((acc, curr) => {

    if (!acc[curr.week]) {
      acc[curr.week] = [];
    }


    acc[curr.week].push(curr);   //<<<--- compare here


    console.log(acc);


    return acc[curr.week][curr.day].push(curr);
  }, {});
```